# MySQL replication/connection failing over SSL

Tags: mysql, ssl

I set up two MySQL servers where one is replicating from the other. They both work perfectly, but once I turn on SSL I get the following error:

`ERROR 2026 (HY000): SSL connection error`

I get the same error running from command line like so:

`mysql --ssl=1 --ssl-ca=/etc/mysql/certificates/ca-cert.pem --ssl-cert=/etc/mysql/certificates/client-cert.pem --ssl-key=/etc/mysql/certificates/client-key.pem --user=slave --password=slavepassword --host=master.url.com`

Both MySQL servers are running on version 5.0.77. There is a difference that MySQL in the master server was compiled under x86_64 while in the slave server under i686. Also both machines are running CentOS 5.

Plus I generated certificates as per this [page](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/secure-create-certs.html).

Any idea for finding a solution?

Answer (score 1):

Regenerate your certificates, using *different common names* for the master and slave